# Repeating items in a column excluding the one item corresponding to times value

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, repeat

the given R script below repeats the given names by 4 times. I need to make it such that when, for each "times" value, the element corresponding to the times value does not appear, e.g. for times = "1", only "David","Murdoch","August" should appear, for times = "2", "Robert","Murdoch","August", for times = 3, "Robert","David","August" should appear and so on. Finally I should get a total of 12 values repeated here. Currently it is 16. Please help me with a scalable solution without loops and if's which is fast as I need to apply it on large data. Also, if "rep" function can be replaced with a faster solution. Thanks and please help.

```
names <- c("Robert","David","Murdoch","August")
names_rep <- rep(names, times = 4)
```

Comment: Please note that `names` is already a predefined function within R. Naming objects after predefined functions is asking for trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think `rep` is the right function here. You can do it using `sapply` where we can skip the respective index position.

```
c(sapply(seq_along(names), function(x) names[-x]))

#[1] "David"   "Murdoch" "August"  "Robert"  "Murdoch" "August" 
#[7] "Robert"  "David"   "August"  "Robert"  "David"   "Murdoch"
```

Comment: Awesome, to the point it, but my question is, say I want to repeat some 10K+ items using this formula, you suggest this will help?

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, actually to make the solution fast, I was looking at finding an alternative to "rep".

Answer (score 1):

We can create with `rep` and then remove the elements

```
v1 <- rep(names, 4)
v1[-seq(1, length(v1), by = 5)]
#[1] "David"   "Murdoch" "August"  "Robert"  "Murdoch"
#[6] "August"  "Robert"  "David"   "August"  "Robert"  "David"  
#[12] "Murdoch"
```

Comment: thank you so much for your effort, I'll look into this.